# Unable to see services with traefik

Tags: docker-compose, docker-swarm, traefik

I'm a beginner and Im a bit confused about how traefik works...

I want to use the app freqtrade (trading bot) as a docker service and replicate it with different type of configuration, if you have 5min you can go check [this guy](https://www.omgthecloud.com/freqtrade-quickly-deploy-your-bot-army/) I want to do the same thing...

But I don't understant why I can't see my app running with traefik  :

What I did :

Configure my domain to my server like that :

[server config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMoqI.png)

And on this machine I create a docker swarm and the treafik service with [this tutorial](https://dockerswarm.rocks/traefik/) and then, my docker compose file look like that :

````
```
version: '3.3'

services:
  traefik:
    # Use the latest v2.2.x Traefik image available
    image: traefik:v2.2
    ports:
      # Listen on port 80, default for HTTP, necessary to redirect to HTTPS
      - 80:80
      # Listen on port 443, default for HTTPS
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - traefik-public

    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          # Make the traefik service run only on the node with this label
          # as the node with it has the volume for the certificates
          - node.labels.traefik-public.traefik-public-certificates == true
      labels:
        # Enable Traefik for this service, to make it available in the public network
        - traefik.enable=true
        # Use the traefik-public network (declared below)
        - traefik.docker.network=traefik-public
        # Use the custom label "traefik.constraint-label=traefik-public"
        # This public Traefik will only use services with this label
        # That way you can add other internal Traefik instances per stack if needed
        - traefik.constraint-label=traefik-public
        # admin-auth middleware with HTTP Basic auth
        # Using the environment variables USERNAME and HASHED_PASSWORD
        - traefik.http.middlewares.admin-auth.basicauth.users=${USERNAME?Variable not set}:${HASHED_PASSWORD?Variable not set}
        # https-redirect middleware to redirect HTTP to HTTPS
        # It can be re-used by other stacks in other Docker Compose files
        - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https
        - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true
        # traefik-http set up only to use the middleware to redirect to https
        # Uses the environment variable DOMAIN
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-http.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`)
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-http.entrypoints=http
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-http.middlewares=https-redirect
        # traefik-https the actual router using HTTPS
        # Uses the environment variable DOMAIN
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`)
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.entrypoints=https
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.tls=true
        # Use the special Traefik service api@internal with the web UI/Dashboard
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.service=api@internal
        # Use the "le" (Let's Encrypt) resolver created below
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.tls.certresolver=le
        # Enable HTTP Basic auth, using the middleware created above
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.middlewares=admin-auth
        # Define the port inside of the Docker service to use
        - traefik.http.services.traefik-public.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
    volumes:
      # Add Docker as a mounted volume, so that Traefik can read the labels of other services
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      # Mount the volume to store the certificates
      - traefik-public-certificates:/certificates
    command:
      # Enable Docker in Traefik, so that it reads labels from Docker services
      - --providers.docker
      # Add a constraint to only use services with the label "traefik.constraint-label=traefik-public"
      - --providers.docker.constraints=Label(`traefik.constraint-label`, `traefik-public`)
      # Do not expose all Docker services, only the ones explicitly exposed
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      # Enable Docker Swarm mode
      - --providers.docker.swarmmode
      # Create an entrypoint "http" listening on port 80
      - --entrypoints.http.address=:80
      # Create an entrypoint "https" listening on port 443
      - --entrypoints.https.address=:443
      # Create the certificate resolver "le" for Let's Encrypt, uses the environment variable EMAIL
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.email=${EMAIL?Variable not set}
      # Store the Let's Encrypt certificates in the mounted volume
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.storage=/certificates/acme.json
      # Use the TLS Challenge for Let's Encrypt
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.tlschallenge=true
      # Enable the access log, with HTTP requests
      - --accesslog
      # Enable the Traefik log, for configurations and errors
      - --log
      # Enable the Dashboard and API
      - --api

volumes:
  # Create a volume to store the certificates, there is a constraint to make sure
  # Traefik is always deployed to the same Docker node with the same volume containing
  # the HTTPS certificates
  traefik-public-certificates:

networks:
  traefik-public:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
```
````

And deploy it :

```
docker stack deploy -c traefik.yml traefik
```

- After that traefik works fine. Why I can't see the port 8080 in my entrypoint ? is it important for others services ?

[Entrypoint traefik](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0r6z.png)

I try to disable the firewall in configuration of  the server and also do `ufw allow 8080` but nothing change...

- I create my a application like I create traefik service with this docker-compose file :

```
---
version: '3'

networks:
  traefik_traefik-public:
    external: true


services:
  freqtrade:
    image: freqtradeorg/freqtrade:stable
    # image: freqtradeorg/freqtrade:develop
    # Use plotting image
    # image: freqtradeorg/freqtrade:develop_plot
    # Build step - only needed when additional dependencies are needed
    # build:
    #   context: .
    #   dockerfile: "./docker/Dockerfile.custom"
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: freqtrade
    volumes:
      - "./user_data:/freqtrade/user_data"
    # Expose api on port 8080 (localhost only)
    # Please read the https://www.freqtrade.io/en/stable/rest-api/ documentation
    # before enabling this.

    networks:
      - traefik_traefik-public
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
    command: >
      trade
      --logfile /freqtrade/user_data/logs/freqtrade.log
      --db-url sqlite:////freqtrade/user_data/tradesv3.sqlite
      --config /freqtrade/user_data/config.json
      --strategy SampleStrategy
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.bot001.tls=true'
      - traefik.http.routers.bot001.rule=Host(`bot001.bots.lordgoliath.com`)'
      - traefik.http.services.bot001.loadbalancer.server.port=8080'
```

and this is a part of the configuation file of the bot (to access to the UI)

```
"api_server": {
        "enabled": true,
        "enable_openapi": true,
        "listen_ip_address": "0.0.0.0",
        "listen_port": 8080,
        "verbosity": "info",
        "jwt_secret_key": "somethingrandom",
        "CORS_origins": ["https://bots.lordgoliath.com"],
        "username": "api",
        "password": "api"
    },
```

then :

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml freqtrade
```

So I have that :

```
goliath@localhost:~/freqtrade_test/user_data$ docker service ls
ID             NAME                  MODE         REPLICAS   IMAGE                           PORTS
nkvpjjztjibg   freqtrade_freqtrade   replicated   1/1        freqtradeorg/freqtrade:stable
6qryu28ute9i   traefik_traefik       replicated   1/1        traefik:v2.2                    *:80->80/tcp, *:443->443/tcp
```

I see the bot running with the command `docker service logs freqtrade_freqtrade`  but
when I try to go on my domain to see it have only the Traefik dashboard and can't see anything else running.

[traefik http](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPtmu.png)
[traefik https](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcZXp.png)

how I can see my app freqtrade running ? how can I access to the bot UI via my domain ?

Thanks !

Sorry for my bad English I hope this is clear enough to understand my problem

**UPDATE**

```
docker service inspect --pretty freqtrade_freqtrade


ID:             o6bpaso69i9n6etybtj09xsqi
Name:           ft1_freqtrade
Labels:
 com.docker.stack.image=freqtradeorg/freqtrade:stable
 com.docker.stack.namespace=ft1
Service Mode:   Replicated
 Replicas:      1
Placement:
 Constraints:   [node.role == manager]
UpdateConfig:
 Parallelism:   1
 On failure:    pause
 Monitoring Period: 5s
 Max failure ratio: 0
 Update order:      stop-first
RollbackConfig:
 Parallelism:   1
 On failure:    pause
 Monitoring Period: 5s
 Max failure ratio: 0
 Rollback order:    stop-first
ContainerSpec:
 Image:         freqtradeorg/freqtrade:stable@sha256:3b2f2acb5b9cfedaa7b07cf56af01d1a750bce4c3054bdbaf40ac27935c984eb
 Args:          trade --logfile /freqtrade/user_data/logs/freqtrade.log --db-url sqlite:////freqtrade/user_data/tradesv3.sqlite --config /freqtrade/user_data/config.json --strategy SampleStrategy
Mounts:
 Target:        /freqtrade/user_data
  Source:       /home/goliath/freqtrade_test/user_data
  ReadOnly:     false
  Type:         bind
Resources:
Networks: traefik_traefik-public
Endpoint Mode:  vip
```

**UPDATE NEW docker-compose.yml**

```
    ---
    version: '3'
    
    networks:
      traefik_traefik-public:
        external: true
services:
       freqtrade:
    image: freqtradeorg/freqtrade:stable
    # image: freqtradeorg/freqtrade:develop
    # Use plotting image
    # image: freqtradeorg/freqtrade:develop_plot
    # Build step - only needed when additional dependencies are needed
    # build:
    #   context: .
    #   dockerfile: "./docker/Dockerfile.custom"
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: freqtrade
    volumes:
      - "./user_data:/freqtrade/user_data"
    # Expose api on port 8080 (localhost only)
    # Please read the https://www.freqtrade.io/en/stable/rest-api/ documentation
    # before enabling this.

    networks:
      - traefik_traefik-public
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
      labels:
      - 'traefik.enabled=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.bot001.tls=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.bot001.rule=Host(`bot001.bots.lordgoliath.com`)'
      - 'traefik.http.services.bot001.loadbalancer.server.port=8080'
    command: >
      trade
      --logfile /freqtrade/user_data/logs/freqtrade.log
      --db-url sqlite:////freqtrade/user_data/tradesv3.sqlite
      --config /freqtrade/user_data/config.json
      --strategy SampleStrategy
```

**UPDATE** `docker network ls`

```
goliath@localhost:~/freqtrade_test$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME                     DRIVER    SCOPE
003e00401b5d   bridge                   bridge    local
9f3d9a222928   docker_gwbridge          bridge    local
09a33afad0c9   host                     host      local
r4u268yenm5u   ingress                  overlay   swarm
bed40e4a5c62   none                     null      local
qo9w45gitke5   traefik_traefik-public   overlay   swarm
```

Comment: I think the `labels` on your freqtrade service need to be nested under the `deploy` key, based on some other examples I saw online. You may also need to add `traefik.enabled=true` since you're setting `providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false` on the traefik service.

Comment: Also, the significance of port 8080 is that it's the port traefik communicates with your actual app on. I.e., clients will hit 80/443 on your host which traefik listens to, and then traefik communicates with the app containers on port 8080 (which should not be opened up to the wider web).

Comment: Thanks for you response @RobertNubel I understand about the 8080 port and I closed It.
I tryed to add  `traefik.enabled=true`  and the `label` on the docker-compose file of my freqtrade but I'm still not able to see somthing in my Traefik dashboard.... I also update the service

Comment: Can you share the output of `docker service inspect --pretty freqtrade_freqtrade`?

Comment: Ok I will update my fist post because it's too long and looks bad in comments

Comment: it's done i put the result on the last section "UPDATE" of my post

Comment: It looks like the labels you specified aren't getting attached to the service. Did you see my earlier note about moving the `labels` block to be nested under the `deploy` section?

Comment: Yes, I put the label section in the deploy section or maybe Im wrong ? ( I put the new file a the end of the post)

Comment: I also put what I have when I enter `docker network ls`

Comment: That does look about right. Hm, I think the next step is to identify whether a) your service is not being added into Traefik or b) Traefik is just not routing your requests to the service. For that, can you see any routers or services listed in the Traefik dashboard which you can access?

Comment: Ok, so i will try to investigate a).

and for b) and I put all screenshot of what i have access in the first post, but there is no valuable information I think... :/ 

thanks again for your time Robert :)

Comment: Ok so it seems I can't put links in my post so I try here  :https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6Ynm.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Llu9.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkeSi.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHztr.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6xK9.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeoXj.png

Comment: So, definitely case A. Looking at this all again, I'm realizing you're deploying Traefik and your app service in two separate docker stacks, which I believe is namespacing them. That might be preventing Traefik from discovering your service. Could you try deploying them into the same stack? E.g., `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml -c traefik.yml freqtrade`. That will probably remove the need for the external network in your main compose yml, too.

Comment: Hello @RobertNubel Ok I delete all the services and did your command to recreate them and this is the result https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CDX7.png 
unfortunately nothing change on my traefik dashboard... I'm not able to see other services than traefik himself :/

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/L3q4ihC.png 
It's look like it's on the good network

Comment: Well, we're at least eliminating complexity, which we can keep doing to narrow down the problem. Can you screenshot docker service inspect results for each service as well?

Comment: yep you're right ! here it is : https://i.imgur.com/8hGcxPA.png  I have only one other services witch is traeffik

Comment: The traefik service itself looks okay. What about docker service inspect on the freqtrade service?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/L3q4ihC.png it look good too I guess

Comment: Okay, I think what might be missing here is the traefik.constraint-label. I believe that the traefik configuration is set up so it will only pick up containers with traefik.constraint-label set to `traefik-public`, so try adding `- traefik.constraint-label=traefik-public` to the labels for your freqtrade service.

Comment: I added the line, remove et deploy everything but im still not able to see my services :/

Comment: Hm... Are there any logs coming out of the Traefik container that might be illuminating? You can add `--log.level=DEBUG` to the command for traefik as well to see if that gets more info.

Comment: logs was a good idea !  https://i.imgur.com/L8UPm2i.png so it's seems it doesn't see my network 'trafik-public' but don't understand because in config file I named it traefik-public like the default name but when I hit the command `docker stack deploy -c traefik.yml -c  tfk1` he rename my network "tfk1_traefik-public"....

Comment: Worth a shot to add the prefix you're seeing (tkf1 or whatnot)  to the configured network name, though the log mentions that it's trying to use the first available network which I'd expect to be that one anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the minimal config you need to integrate in order to see the traefik dashboard on localhost:8080

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    command: |
      --api.insecure=true
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Then, your minimal configuration to get traefik to route `example.com` to itself:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

networks:
  public:
    attachable: true
    name: traefik

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    command: |
      --api.insecure=true
      --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      --providers.docker.swarmmode
      --providers.docker.network=traefik
    ports:
      - 80:80
    networks:
    - public
    deploy:
      labels:
        traefik.enable: "true"
        traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule: Host(`example.com`)
        traefik.http.services.traefik.loadbalancer.server.port: 8080
```

Now, minimal https support - using Traefik self signed certs to start with. Note that we configure tls on the https entrypoint, which means traefik implicitly creates http and https variants for each router.

```yaml
version: "3.9"

networks:
  public:
    attachable: true
    name: traefik

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    command: |
      --api.insecure=true
      --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      --providers.docker.swarmmode
      --providers.docker.network=traefik
      --entrypoints.http.address=:80
      --entrypoints.https.address=:443
      --entrypoints.https.http.tls=true
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
        - node.role == manager
    ports:
#      - 8080:8080
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
    - public
    deploy:
      labels:
        traefik.enable: "true"
        traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule: Host(`example.com`)
        traefik.http.services.traefik.loadbalancer.server.port: 8080
```

At this point, gluing in your le config should be simple.

---

Your freqtrade stack compose would need to be this. If this is a single node swarm, just omit the placement constraints, but when the swarm is large enough to have workers, then tasks that don't need to be on managers should explicitly be kept on workers.

Traefik needs to talk to the swarm api over the docker socket, which is on manager nodes only, which is why it must be `node.role==manager`.

```yaml
version: "3.9"
    
networks:
  traefik:
    external: true

services:
  freqtrade:
    image: freqtradeorg/freqtrade:stable
    command: ...
    volumes: ...
    networks:
    - traefik
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
        - node.role == worker
      restart_policy:
        max_attempts: 5
      labels:
        traefik.enabled: "true"
        traefik.http.routers.bot001.rule: Host(`bot001.bots.lordgoliath.com`)
        traefik.http.services.bot001.loadbalancer.server.port: 8080
```

Comment: Thanks for you're help Chris !  I still miss something, I put this config file for my traefik but when I want to deploy my other service freqtrade I not able to see it...I only have traefik running